# How to create pagination in eager loaded relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-8, eager-loading, eloquent-relationship, eager

I want the pagination to happen in eager loaded relation but when I am using it I am getting an error.
`Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.` This only happens when I use `{{ $SubjectReport->reports->links() }}` in views rather than that everything is working fine as when I remove this `{{ $SubjectReport->reports->links() }}` the page loads with the number set in paginate method.

This is what I have tried so far

Here is my controller

```
$SubjectReport = Subject::with(['assesment.curriculumUnit',
    'reports' => function($q) {
    $q->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(2);
}])->where('id',2)->first();
 
return view('learner.assesment_reports',compact('SubjectReport'));
```

Here is my view

```
@foreach ($SubjectReport->reports as $key => $report)

@endforeach

{{ $SubjectReport->reports->links() }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `with` doesn't work with pagination correctly. It's return only portion of data in `Collection` instead `Paginator`.
The best way to paginate relation is:

```
$SubjectReport = Subject::with('assesment.curriculumUnit')->where('id',2)->first();
$SubjectReport->reports = $SubjectReport->reports()->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(2);
```